# Not able to connect react native expo frontend with node js API on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

Not able to connect my react native expo app with my node js API. I am running app on physical device. I used same API with my react.js app which connect successfully.

BACKEND
At API:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8800;
const host = '0.0.0.0'
  
app.listen(port,host,()=>{
    connect()
    console.log("connected to backend")
})
```

FRONTEND:
react native packege,json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "proxy": "http://192.168.1.10:8800/api"
}
```

react native registration page:

```
onSubmit={(values, action) => {
        const { cpassword, ...data } = values;
        console.log(data);
        const resp = axios
          .post("auth/register", data)
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(data);
            if (err && err.resp) console.log("error", err);
            Alert.alert("Registration", "Something wrong", [
              {
                text: "Cancel",
                onPress: () => navigation.navigate("Register"),
                style: "cancel"
              },
              { text: "OK", onPress: () => navigate }
            ]);
          });
        if (resp) {
          Alert.alert("Registration", "Sign up Successfully!", [
            {
              text: "Cancel",
              onPress: () => navigation.navigate("Login"),
              style: "cancel"
            },
            { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK") }
          ]);
        }
      }}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Having trouble to  make connection between FRONTEND  and API.  FRONTEND  is react native app and API is build on react native expo.